# Как передать ID в качестве параметра?

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть 4 кнопки и 2 текстовых поля По 2 кнопки на инкремент и декремент каждого поля, написал 1 общую функция, но при попытке вызова в plusScore, teamId горит красным. Как можно исправить?

```
    public void Button1(View v) {
        plusScore("TextView1", 1)
    }

    public void Button2(View v) {
        plusScore("TextView1", -1)
    }

    public void Button3(View v) {
        plusScore("TextView2", 1)
    }

    public void Button4(View v) {
        plusScore("TextView2", -1)
    }

    private void plusScore(String teamId, int score) {        
        TextView TeamScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teamId);
        int tmp = Integer.parseInt(TeamScore.getText().toString());
        tmp += score;
        TeamScore.setText(tmp);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вашего случая:

```
int ResID = getResources().getIdentifier(teamID, "id", getPackageName());
TextView TeamScore = (TextView) findViewById(ResID);
```

**Ответ был найден здесь:**  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865244/android-using-findviewbyid-with-a-string-in-a-loop